# How do I convince Splunk that a backslash inside a CSV field is not an escape character?

Tags: csv, splunk

I have the following row in a CSV file that I am ingesting into a Splunk index:

```
"field1","field2","field3\","field4"
```

Excel and the default Python CSV reader both correctly parse that as 4 separate fields. Splunk does not. It seems to be treating the backslash as an escape character and interpreting `field3","field4` as a single mangled field. It is my understanding that the standard escape character for double quotes inside a quoted CSV field is another double quote, according to RFC-4180:

> "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."

Why is Splunk treating the backslash as an escape character, and is there any way to change that configuration via props.conf or any other way? I have set:

```
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = csv
KV_MODE = none
```

for this sourcetype in props.conf, and it is working fine for rows without backslashes in them.

UPDATE: Yeah so Splunk's CSV parsing is indeed [not RFC-4180 compliant](https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/Splunk-Apps/issues/159#issuecomment-756410117), and there's not really any workaround that I could find. In the end I changed the upstream data pipeline to output JSON instead of CSVs for ingestion by Splunk. Now it works fine. Let this be a cautionary tale if anyone stumbles across this question while trying to parse CSVs in Splunk!

Comment: Splunk's interpreting the "`\"`" *exactly* as you describe from the RFC citation. A backslash before a quote mark is *precisely* how you escape it. That Excel *isn't* following the rules is...concerning, honestly :)

Comment: @warren the RFC says you escape a double quote by "preceding it with another double quote", not a backslash. As in, `""` rather than `\"`

Comment: but *commas* are being used to separate fields - with *quotes* being used to contain the values in a given field :)

Comment: @warren yes. And then if you have a double quote inside a quoted field value, it must be preceded by another double quote. Backslashes should be irrelevant. See section 2 paragraph 7: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180
Excel, Python, and every other application I have tried follow this standard. Splunk apparently does not.

Comment: Also for reference, backlash appears nowhere in the grammar:
`
file = [header CRLF] record *(CRLF record) [CRLF]

   header = name *(COMMA name)

   record = field *(COMMA field)

   name = field

   field = (escaped / non-escaped)

   escaped = DQUOTE *(TEXTDATA / COMMA / CR / LF / 2DQUOTE) DQUOTE

   non-escaped = *TEXTDATA

   COMMA = %x2C

   CR = %x0D ;

  DQUOTE =  %x22;

   LF = %x0A;

   CRLF = CR LF;

   TEXTDATA =  %x20-21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-7E;
`

Comment: Since the ascii code for '\' is 0x5C (0x2D < 0x5C < 0x7E), a compliant csv parser must consider it TEXTDATA

Comment: @SteveCox exactly! That was my reading as well. I just wish the Splunk documentation would mention that it does not comply to the dominant CSV standard :(